# Could not run ORACLE IMP/EXP command from IIS

Tags: oracle, iis, import

I have a service hosted in IIS. That service is responsible to execute a batch file. that batch file contains IMP Oracle command (calling to IMPORT by the oracle imp.exe file).

The problem is that this command is not being executed (if the batch file contains any simple command such as create new file - this is working fine). So I guess that this is a permission issue (I have tried to set permission on some directories without success).

can anyone knows what i do wrong ?

Thanks,
hagai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS probably runs as a service with little knowledge of the environment. We run exp/imp (or actually nowadays the improved impdp/expdp which is stable and required starting 11.2.0.3) from a batch scheduler and had the same initial problems.

Please make sure that you have the environment variables correctly configured:

- ORACLE_HOME
- TNS_ADMIN when used
- NLS_LANG when used
- PATH (including %ORACLE_HOME%\bin)

Or set them from your batch script.

To get better logging you might want to add something like the following to your execution of imp/exp:

```
set LOGFILE=%TEMPDIRSOMEWHERE%\oracle-imp.log
imp ...options... >>%LOGFILE% 2>&1
```

If you receive errors you don't understand in the logfile, pleae add them to your original question.

Did this solve the problem for you?

Comment: hi Guido.
I see this in the Log file:
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 1017 encountered
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon deniedUsername:

Comment: Great you have found the cause. Provide a username/password on command line or in control file. Such as `imp userid=usr/pwd@service`. You might want to load these from environment variables or a profile option or so.